# How to properly deal with a cable company which regularily does not provide the bandwidth that is being payed for?

Tags: contract-law, internet

We are having a contract with a cable company managing our internet and phone connections. We very regularily (even at on the dot schedules) do not have any internet or telephone network connection in our house.

What can we do to either terminate the contract prematurely or make them keep their part of the agreement?

We are living in Germany.

Comment: Is there a governmental or non-governmental regulatory body that deals with complaints and regulations of internet and phone companies? That's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here in America, the FCC, Federal Communications Commission regulates these matters and it is most definitely within their scope of concern. From everything that I've heard and read, servic in Germany is supposed to be 10 times what it is here. If it's a matter of getting out of her contract, I would have extensive documentation. What you were claiming would be very hard to prove so you need video and independent source.

My impression would be that you would have a regulatory agency similar to our FCC.